# How do I properly pose this tail with Rigify?

Tags: rigging, rigify

Another question regarding Rigify, how do I rotate this tail individualy?

My goal is to position the tail like this so that I can properly model a skirt for the character.

[image: The desired result, save for the widget placement.]

The solution I found is to get the tail the closest to the desired pose as possible using `tail_master`, select all of the `tweak_tail` widgets, and pivot the tail by `tweak_base_tail`.

[image: Getting the tail in the desired position.]

However, the rig no longer functions quite right, and when I try to reposition the tail the results get messy.

[image: The tail warps as I grab the widgets.]

I've also tried adjusting the "Tail Follow" slider under "Rig Main Properties" in the Item menu, but it didn't seem to make a difference at all.

Am I doing this right?

You can find the .blend file [here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r9nWClF729mnQGAvCBi4xpz82bfLS-EV/view?usp=sharing) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add the blend file to your question ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: Still waiting for the blend file so I can take a look.

Comment: Hey! Unfortunately I don't agree with the Terms of Service of this site, namely the "User Content" section, but you can find the .blend file [here!](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r9nWClF729mnQGAvCBi4xpz82bfLS-EV/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Found a solution asking around on blenderartists.org!](https://blenderartists.org/t/how-do-i-pose-this-tail-with-a-rigify-rig/1339013/11?u=meattail)

I'm surprised I didn't think of trying this earlier, but I just had to rotate the green lines!

[image: Rotating the tail to the desired position.]

Another thing I've noticed is that rotating the green lines actually rotates along the blue circles, which is what I've been trying to do. The blue circles can't seem to be rotated themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The balls are used to articulate as a refinement of the pose done by the rings who are initially posed by the tail master.

Start with With everything reset to default, then
adjust your tail in this order:

1. Tail master = least accurate
2. Rings = more accurate
3. Balls = fine tuning

Comment: hey! sorry for the late reply, i recently had my wedding and i've been busy with work and uni admissions lately!

i understand what the widgets do, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get the tail to do what i'd like. more specifically, the `tweak_tail` widgets don't appear to be able to rotate. i just need to rotate the tail on [this](https://i.imgur.com/isb4BUk.png) axis!